# Creating a plane in Edit Mode

Tags: modeling

Does someone know how to do this?

I read a comment saying “Create a plane in *Edit Mode* <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> Center. Activate magnet + vertex +closest. Extrude dot .” but I'm confused because I'm a newbie

[image]

Comment: What is **this**?

Comment: Adding new geometry on top of the existing one...? @Lukasz-40sth

Comment: You can create that face by hitting **F** after selecting either all vertices that need to be connected to that face (here 4 vertices) OR all edges (here 2 edges)

Comment: **ALT + M** ,This only collapses the selected vertices towards the center, does not do what you are looking for or plan to do

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to activate the selection of edges, select 2 or more edges where you want to fill with a face and press

- <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd>
- select **bridge edge loop**

You can also do this by selecting edges and filling by pressing <kbd>F</kbd>

[image]
[image]